# Trouble connecting a Rails 4 app to redis over an ssh tunnel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, redis, centos, resque

We're running a redis server in EC2 and to protect the connections established ssh tunnels from our production app machines to the redis instance. We used something like `autossh -M 0 -f -NT -L6379:localhost:6379 -i /path/to/ec2.key root@ec2-xxxx.compute-1-amazonaws.com` to establish persistent tunnels.

Now here's the problem, this seems to work about 90% of the time, but occasionally for whatever reason redis throws `Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (ECONNREFUSED)` when initializing Resque from environment.rb.  The given box already has numerous redis connections from other processes (unicorn & resque threads), so I know the tunnel is working. If I rerun the command it's almost always successful and is able to establish the connection without a hitch.

We're running Rails 4, Resque 1.24.1, Redis gem 3.0.5 and redis-server 2.6.12 on CentOS 6 on an m2-xlarge.

Any ideas? When this happens during deploy it's extremely frustrating as it kills capistrano, it's also causing sporadic failures in our nightly jobs that spin up their own rails environments.